# Formula for $\pi$ using primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

In one of his videos (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrRMnzANHHs), Matt Parker introduces the following formula for $\pi$ using primes:

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{5}\right)\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{7}\right)\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{11}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{13}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{17}\right)\cdot \ldots=\frac{2}{\pi}$$
Each term is $\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)$ if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  Otherwise, the term is $\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$.

Could somebody please explain this formula to me?

Comment: Apparently this is discussed in Blatner, D. The Joy of Pi. New York: Walker, p. 110, 1997.

Comment: Are you familiar with the $\zeta$ function and with the fact $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$? If so, combine the previous equality with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80 (note the last section of the article) to get your result. Does this help?

Comment: By "combine" I meant "hold breath and make formal manipulations..."

Comment: @peterag Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @peterag I got that, for some reason, the above expression should be equal to $\frac{3}{2\pi}$, which is $\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

Comment: @ peterag NVM, I finally got it